# /usr/bin/env: php: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, ssh, php

I want to use .sh script for deployment of my app. That script is on my home server (Ubuntu 15.10 Server), marked as executable. Access to this script is done through ssh, using [this](http://cybermashup.com/2013/05/14/restrict-ssh-logins-to-a-single-command/) tutorial, I have set up ssh login, that runs that script. So basically I just call `ssh deployer@XXX.com someArguments` and it runs my script with `someArguments` as parameters. The user `deployer` has uid=0, so its basically `root` (this will be changed in the future, I have set it only to eliminate permissions problems until it works fine).

And here is where the things get tricky. The script reports `/usr/bin/env: php: No such file or directory` at command `/bin/composer install` (using [Composer](https://getcomposer.org)). Things are more weird the more I look on that script. Before this line, there is also called `/bin/composer self-update` and `/bin/composer -V`, which both runs correctly and displays correct output.

I have checked following things:

- `/usr/bin/env php -v` displays correct PHP version (same as `/usr/bin/php -v`)
- `whereis php` displays `php: /usr/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz`
- `php5-cli` package is installed and newest version
- `$PATH` contains `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`
- `which env` displays `/usr/bin/env`

I have also tried following things:

- running the script directly as `bash deploy.sh` under root (since it is same as that user) - works perfectly without errors
- running failing commands directly - also perfectly without errors

So this seems to me as very specific case, why this command does not work. I spent 12 hours of debugging it and I am out of ideas here.

**P.S.:** Similar error (`/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory`) occurs when there is `bower install` (using [Bower](http://bower.io/)), but *not* when running `npm install` (using [NPM](http://npmjs.com)).

Comment: Run `sh deploy` instead of `bash deploy` (maybe some bashism).  How did you check the "_following things_"?  I recommend to check them in the script, so that you can discover eventual overrides and sanitations of envs.

Comment: regarding "*following things*": I added them to start of deploy.sh script and they output these things I put down to question. Same output is when I run them alone, though.

Comment: `sh deploy` and `bash deploy` both gives same results

Comment: Show that line here, please.
I recommend you to replace your **php** command at this line in your script with output to file to examine environment variables at the moment of calling /usr/bin/env: `/usr/bin/env > environment.txt`

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that line endings and/or invisible spaces aren't causing the problem.

Remove the spaces in the first line of the script and insert new ones, making sure not to hold CTRL while pressing space.

Also, make sure you don't have DOS line endings (CR+LF).
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82726/convert-dos-line-endings-to-linux-line-endings-in-vim for details.

Comment: I am using IDE, which automatically checks (and converts) CR+LF to LF only, removes BOM and cares about white characters, but I double-checked it, and it appears ok (still not working though). Thanks anyway

Answer (score 5):

The `env` command will look through a user's `$PATH` to find the first executable of the given name. So, `/usr/bin/env php` will look for an executable file called `php` in any of the directories in the `$PATH` of the user running it.

In your case, that's almost certainly because when running a command over `ssh`, you don't start a full shell and don't actually read your shell's initialization files. You can check this by running this command (note the single quotes):

```
ssh deployer@XXX.com 'echo $PATH'
```

And comparing the output to what you get if you `ssh deployer@XXX.com` and *then* run `echo $PATH`. On my system. for example:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:

$ ssh localhost 'echo $PATH'
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Therefore, the `$PATH` that your script has access to when run with `ssh deployer@XXX.com` is not the same as when you log in to test it.

In any case, the simple solution is to use the full path to the interpreter instead of `env`. Both `env` and full paths have their [benefits and drawbacks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/22222) but, in this case, the path is safer:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

Comment: ITYM "**note** the single quotes" not "**not**".

Comment: I am actually using full paths everywhere, as I mentioned in my question, the error is reported **inside** `composer install` command, which i obviously cannot modify. Also `$PATH` is ok, as I mentioned in my question too, I checked all the things by adding them into the script and running remotely via ssh login.

Also I can not check the `ssh deployer@XXX.com 'echo $PATH'` as you stated, since my ssh login is limited to one script only, but I hovever did check it when I add $PATH to that script (stated above)

Anyway, thank you for your answer, and accept +1 for explaining me the `env` thing

Comment: @TomášBlatný well, you're using env somewhere, or you wouldn't be seeing that error. I don't know composer but you will probably have to copy or link the php executable to a directory in its path. This sort of thing is hard to debug since there are so many things each depending on the other.

Comment: Thats true, `env` is actually called inside composer. But this does not solve the problem, why some composer calls pass, and some not. However I will futher investigate this by looking into its code. Thanks for your time

Comment: @TomášBlatný I am guessing that those that pass are calling binaries that are in a directory that is in whatever limited PATH composer uses. Try linking the ones that don't work into the directory holding the ones that do. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way.... change the user's shell as the script.

### /etc/passwd

```
Before:
deploy:x:0:0:,,,:/root:/bin/bash

After:
deploy:x:0:0:,,,:/root:/scripts/deploy.sh
```

Example script (make sure execute bit is set chmod +x)

### /scripts/deploy.sh

```
#!/bin/bash 
PATH=$PATH:/moo etc...
moo.sh
```

[image: Sample]
Works everytime! You should even be able to use the script to troubleshoot/debug any env variables which you may feel are unset etc ... also the handling arguments being passed into ssh will work as well..

*Note: Its Best Practice to always FULLY QUALIFY the paths for any scripts, executables, etc.. Above is just an example which allows the default path to be set to call moo.sh within the moo folder ;)*

That was easy.. Thanks for posting..

Reference: [/etc/passwd format](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/)

Comment: Nice answer, but I actually never use the user on server directly, I always `ssh` to server, and by lane in `authorized_keys`, the script gets called and then connection ends. How shall I modify `authorized_keys` to keep this working?

Comment: It should work the same. You would be authenticating via key and as long as the shell is set to the script for the remote account in question within the remote server's /etc/passwd file the script will execute. I'll add a screenshot to my post shortly.

Comment: @Dave can't wait for your book

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it did not solve my problem, but was for me the most interesting and actually solved other problems I had. Gave you the bounty, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that `bash` needs a reset to its hash table?

If so, you might try adding `hash -r` somewhere in your script, which forces the shell to look through `$PATH` again rather than relying on (possibly outdated) info from the hash table.

When needed, `hash` can also enable the shell to remember paths to executables installed in non-standard locations using the `-p` option, or forget paths with the `-d` option.

Sources:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86017/121251
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22543353/2146843

Comment: This did not solved the problem for me, however its a good knowledge, so I added you a +1

Answer (score 1):

Looks like maybe you need to add php to your path. Try:

```
vim ~/.bashrc
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/php
export PATH
```

You might also want to check where your php lives to be sure that the path there is correct. Try:

```
which php
```

Comment: Well this is not the problem, since `php -v` outputs correct PHP version and `composer --version` outputs composer version. As I said, problem is in one command only.

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that you have a path problem since your deploy script can't find things that are definitely on the path when you do a normal ssh login.

First thing to do to confirm you have a PATH issue is to update your deploy script to log the output of `env` or at least `echo $PATH`.  I am guessing that the way your deploy script is called, $PATH is not set as you would expect.  This debug output will confirm/deny my theory.

I looked at the tutorial you followed.  You should probably make sure at update the `command=` to be `command="/bin/sh /path/to/your/script..."` if you haven't already to make sure your script is run by the right shell.

If you do have a PATH problem, a quick/dirty fix is just to explicitly set PATH at the beginning of your deploy script.

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

## Detailed explanation and further options...

On linux when commands are run they inherit the environment of their parent process.

When you login as a normal user via SSH there are things that happen (like running /etc/bashrc /etc/profile ~/.bash_profile ~/.bashrc etc).  At that point you have may have updated your process's environment by doing things like `export PATH="$PATH:~/mybin"` in those scripts.  Now any future processes that you run will inherit your current environment.

Running a command instead of getting a login shell means that command is run by the ssh daemon and will inherit the environment of the ssh daemon process...which is likely different than your environment as a logged in user.

[The man page for authorized keys](http://man.he.net/man5/authorized_keys) covers what happens after authentication.  Regarding environment:

> 6. Reads the file ~/.ssh/environment, if it exists, and users are
>                  allowed to change their environment.  See the
>                  PermitUserEnvironment option in sshd_config(5).

So the appropriate place to configure environment for the process is in `~/.ssh/environment` where `~` is the home directory for the user that is authenticated to run the command.  You also need to check your sshd_config to make sure PermitUserEnvironment is allowed.

`~/.ssh/environment` format is also specified in the man page of course.

> ```
>          This file is read into the environment at login (if it exists).
>          It can only contain empty lines, comment lines (that start with
>          '#'), and assignment lines of the form name=value.  The file
>          should be writable only by the user; it need not be readable by
>          directory becomes accessible.  This file should be writable only
>          by the user, and need not be readable by anyone else.
> ```

An alternative way to specify the environment without using the above mentioned method is to use the `environment="NAME=value"` option in the authorized_keys file.  See the man page I linked above for details.

Comment: Regarding `Without knowing exactly how you have setup your deploy script to run`: in my question at the begining, there is a link, how I set it up (using `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Thanks for the tip with updating command, I tried it, but unfortunatelly with no difference. I will however futher investigate this and try different shells. Please accept a +1 for that idea.

Comment: Did you try updating your deploy script to print out the current $PATH?  Could you post the result?  If it doesn't match what you expect, then you can just try setting the PATH explicitly as I suggested at the beginning of your deploy script.